# SimpleDB as Denormalized DB

Tags: sql, optimization, amazon-simpledb

In an environment where you have a relational database which handles all business transactions is it a good idea to utilise SimpleDB for all data queries to have faster and more lightweight search?

So the master data storage would be a relational DB which is "replicated"/"transformed" into SimpleDB to provide very fast read only queries since no JOINS and complicated subselects are needed.

Answer (score 2):

What you're considering smells of premature optimization ...

Have you benchmarked your application? Have you identified your search queries as a performance bottleneck? Have you correctly implemented indexes into your database?

IF (and that's a big if) there's no way using a relational database to offer decent search times to your users, going NOSQL might be something worth considering ... but not before !

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDB is a good technology but its claim to fame is not faster queries than a relational database. Offloading queries to replicated SimpleDB is not likely to significantly improve your query response time.

Answer (score 0):

I am still finding it hard to believe, but our experiments show that a round trip from and EC2 instance to simpledb is averaging out to 300milliseconds or so, on a good day!  On a bad day we've seen it go down to 1.5sec.  This is for a single insert.  I'd love to see somebody replicate the experiment to verify these results, but as it is... simpledb is no solution for anything but post processing- in the request/response cycle it would just be way to slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is largely read-only, try using indexed views. Otherwise, cache the data in the application.